# how i can change root url?

Tags: ee2, url

i am using "example.com" URL for magento and "example.com/info/blog" URL for expression engine blog access now client want to access expression engine blog in root URL "example.com/blog" is it possible with coding ?

i want to remove "info" from URL i installed expression engine in "info" folder but i want to access expression engine from magento URL "example.com" not from "example.com/info/"

please guide me
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try out the "include list method" from the old wiki page. Instead of RewriteRule to index.php, use a RewriteRule to info/index.php/$1

*update: tested on my localhost*

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 ^(blog|home|TemplateGroup|P[0-9]{2,8}) [NC] 
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ info/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

i would try-out several things on a local dev machine first. You have to test for site-index and site-url etc. so that {path=} variables still work, or otherwise you have set a custom global variable for {site_root} or something to use for urls in the blog. EE does have to know it's path to the main index.php for various actions (e.g. info/index.php?ACT=xx)

http://web.archive.org/web/20120831062016/http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with ExpressionEngine. It's right in the manual - h[ow to remove index.php](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) (which I assume is info, on your system) from URLs. These directions are for version 2.7.1, your version may be older, but ellislab does have older versions of the help documentation available (2.4.4, 2.5.5, 2.6.1, 2.7.1)

If this answer won't help you, please edit your question to let us know what version of EE you're using, and what OS and server software is on your server.

Comment: Hi Leigh "info" is folder were we installed expression-engine. it is not like "index.php"

Comment: Okay - good to clarify. (You might want to edit your original post and specify that.) There are ways to remove one or more folders from a URL path, using the .htaccess file...but why not just MOVE the EE installation up a level, and put it into a folder called "blog"? That isn't a coding solution, and you had asked for a coding solution; but in the long run, it's cleaner and will mean fewer problems with both EE and with other applications (and all their plugins.)